# Eclipse Mars crashes on attempting to open the POM.xml file

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, pom.xml

I am using Eclipse Mars, and setting up a hello world maven project. As soon as I try to open the pom.xml, Eclipse crashes with a memory error. I tried increasing the memory argument but it didn't help. Below is the eclipse.ini file.... any tips ?

```
-startupplugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.libraryplugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-productorg.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction 
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I used to get "Out of memory" messages from the m2e integration, but the eclipse was not crashing, it was just "recommending" me to restart it. Deleting the local maven cache fixed the problem.

Comment: What version of Eclipse Mars? Mars is still in development with the final release due next month.

Answer (score -1):

When you open POM.xml that time it tries to load/download dependent dependencies and it reindexing the pom dependencies.

This is causing overhead for memory..and if Xms value is very low..then may be the effect as it crashes.

try with maven ->disable dependencies...and check if it crashesh...

Comment: Completely wrong. Xms means "The heap size will be no less than X". In other words - it specifies the **minimal** (and the initial) size of the heap. On the other hand Xmx specifies the maximum heap size.